# How to connect python with a database using tsnnames.ora file?

Tags: python, database, oracle, jupyter, cx-oracle

I am using Oracle 11g client(64 bit) with 64 bit jupyter notebook.
I want to connect desktop jupyter version with a secure zone database.

Comment: Did you check the cx_oracle doc about how to connect python to an oracle db? it's the same thing in jupyter. Either export your env vars before starting the notebook, or inside it (using the os module, os.environ['TNS_ADMIN ']=.....

Comment: For ease of reference, the Python doc mentioned is [Connecting to Oracle Database](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html).